# Energy dependence on bragg peak width

Tags: particle-physics, radiation, protons, medical-physics

If you look at this plot of proton Bragg peak at different energies.

[image]

You can see that the Bragg peak shifts right (which makes sense) but also the height and I think the width of the brag peak is also reduced and widened, Physically, why does this happen? I suspect it has something to do with the 1/v^2 stopping power dependence.

Comment: What are the units for the x- and y-axes on your plot?

Comment: x is depth in water (mm) and I'm not sure about y but I suspect its related to the energy deposited or something along those lines.

It's not my plot I got it from here, I only intended it to illustrate my question. 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269230836_Geant4_electromagnetic_physics_improving_simulation_performance_and_accuracy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protons lose energy in the material in a random process. If you fire a 150 MeV proton beam into material the protons all have (at the start) 150 MeV (apart from the beam energy spread from the accelerator which is small).   If you fire a 230 MeV proton beam into material then they all start with 230 MeV and after 160 mm (from your plot) they have an energy of 150 MeV, but that's an average value, some will have more and some less. (Google the Landau Distribution for details if you want them). So some have a somewhat larger than average range in the rest of the target and some have a somewhat smaller: the peak is spread out.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you are saying because you are penetrating deeper you are engaging in more statistical processes and hence spreading the peak?

Comment: Absolutely. The spread in energy translates to a spread in range

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks!